# Error #1009 only on frame 2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

it hilights line two of the section and says cannot access null object but only on frame two
if on the main document i set it to go to frame 1 it works perfect char is added by child

Ground block class

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Ground_1 extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Ground_1() 
        {
            //constructor code
            trace(root);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
        function loop(e:Event)
        {
            //loop
            if(!root)
            {
                return;
            }
            for(var i:int=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                //solid ground
                trace("Char :", Main(root).char);

                if(this.hitTestPoint(MovieClip(root).char.x,MovieClip(root).char.y,true))
                {
                    MovieClip(root).char.y --;
                    MovieClip(root).char.Yvelocity = 0;
                    MovieClip(root).char.canJump = true;
                }
                //Cieling
                if(this.hitTestPoint(MovieClip(root).char.x,MovieClip(root).char.y-25,true))
                {
                    MovieClip(root).upPressed = false;
                    MovieClip(root).char.Yvelocity = 0;
                    MovieClip(root).char.y ++;
                }
                //Walls
                if(this.hitTestPoint(MovieClip(root).char.x+MovieClip(root).char.width/2,MovieClip(root).char.y-21,true))
                {
                    if(MovieClip(root).rightPressed)
                    {
                        MovieClip(root).rightPressed = false;
                        MovieClip(root).char.x -= MovieClip(root).char.speed;
                    }
                }
                else if(this.hitTestPoint(MovieClip(root).char.x-MovieClip(root).char.width/2,MovieClip(root).char.y-21,true))
                {
                    if(MovieClip(root).leftPressed)
                    {
                        MovieClip(root).leftPressed = false;
                        MovieClip(root).char.x += MovieClip(root).char.speed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Document Main

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        //KeyPressed
        var upPressed:Boolean = false;
        var downPressed:Boolean = false;
        var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
        var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
        var rPressed:Boolean = false;

        var char:player;

        public function Main()
        {
            //constructor code
            this.gotoAndStop(1);
            //Character
            char = new player();
            char.x = starter.x;
            char.y = starter.y;
            addChild(char);
            //starter
            starter.visible = false;
            //Event Listeners
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upHandler);
        }
        function loop(e:Event)
        {
            //loop

            //cam
            Cam.y = char.y-50
            Cam.x = char.x
            Cam.visible = false;

            //Restart
            if(rPressed)
            {
                char.x = starter.x;
                char.y = starter.y;
                char.scaleX = 1;
                char.health = 6;
                trace("Restart");
                rPressed = false;
            }
        }
        function downHandler(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //down
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                upPressed = true;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                downPressed = true;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                rightPressed = true;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                leftPressed = true;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
            {
                rPressed = true;
            }
        }
        function upHandler(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //up
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                upPressed = false;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.R)
            {
                rPressed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely `char` does not exist on the root timeline when this code executes.   Nobody can give you a good answer though without knowing more about your code & context

Comment: the char is added in the Main Document with addchild not to a specific frame, and i works on frame one

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis and it is only if i delete on of the ground blocks.if i make an exact copy of the frame(with F6) it works.ech ground block is an instance of a class added from library not as child

Comment: same thing happens with my enemy class it says the null object is the Char. but the char isnt added to a specific frame i just did [addChild(char)] on the Main document class

Comment: PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Show how you define `char`,  is it inside a class file?  If so, it'll need the public qualifier to be accessible from other places.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis ok look at the update

Comment: it doesnt have public before var char. but other classes can acces it but only if the main time line is on frame 1. i changed it to "public var char:player;" but that didnt change anything

Comment: Ok, then maybe your problem is with root and not char (you should leave public in there though).   `root` `stage` and `parent` are null until after an object has been added to the stage.  If you try to access them before that, they will cause the error you are receiving.   How is your "Ground block class" added to the stage and when.  You want to make sure that loop function is only running when it's on the stage.

Comment: so the ground block class i dragg each block onto stage from the library

Comment: but when is that `loop` function called?    before the line that is throwing the error,  do `trace("root:", root)`, and if it's `null` or `undefined` then that is indeed the problem

Comment: trace("root:",root) in the ground class init function gives me                 
            "root: [object Main]" in the output

Comment: Ok, so root is not the problem.  If (on the line prior to the error) do `trace("char: ", Main(root).char)` does it output `char: [object player]`?

Comment: Main(root) not MovieClip(root)?

Comment: If Main is your documentClass (which is the root), then they are essential the same.  Casting as Main gives you better compile time checking and code hints

Comment: Ok if i do trace(""char :""Main(root).char) it outputs "Char : [object player]"

Comment: What code is on frame 2?   The code you first shared, I can see now (after your edits) that it's not frame code but part of your Ground_1 class.  We need to know the exact line of code that is throwing the error.

Comment: the error comes from the first line that says "if(this.hitTestPoint(MovieClip(root).char.x,MovieClip(root).char.y,true))"  in the ground_1 class

Comment: ok if i run trace("char :", Main(root).char) it says char :[Object:player]. but if i run it in debug mode it highlits the trace line right above the if statement and give the null object error. line 20 of ground class

Comment: At the start of your  ground class's `loop` function,  put `if(!root) return;`

Comment: OK I DID THAT AND IT SEEMS TO BE WORKING HOW DOES THAT HELP? (updated the question)

Comment: It goes back to my third comment.  Root is null until an item is added to the stage.  I'll make a proper answer that explains it all

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!! you fixed it as far as i can tell. Got to go bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `root` is null the first time the `loop` function runs in your `Ground_1` instance(s).

The `root`, `parent` & `stage` vars of a display object are only populated when said display object is added to to the display list. In the case of root & stage the parent (and any grand parents) must also be added so that the top most parent/grandparent is the stage itself.

In the document class, there is no guarantee that in it's constructor (the function `Main`) that it will be on the display list already.  Sometimes (usually) stage has a value in the document class constructor, but not always.

Here is an example of how things are executed in your code:

1. Program starts
2. Document Class constructor runs (Main function)
3. Your document class timeline objects are instantiated (this is when their constructor functions run
4. Your document timeline objects are added to the displaylist
5. Your timeline objects first frames are run

Asynchronously, sometime after #1 and before #4, the document class is added to the stage.  Since you start listening for ENTER_FRAME right in your Ground_1 constructor, it's not guaranteed that stage/root are available.

As a result, you need to wait until it's safe by listening for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event.

```
public function Main(){
    //if stage doesn't exist yet, wait for it, then call stageReady
    if(!stage){
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageReady);
    }else{
        stageReady();
    }
}

private function stageReady(e:Event = null):void {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
        //Character
        char = new player();
        char.x = starter.x;
        char.y = starter.y;
        addChild(char);
        //starter
        starter.visible = false;
        //Event Listeners
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upHandler);
}
```

Likewise, in your `Ground_1` class, you need to do the same:

```
public function Ground_1() 
{
        //constructor code
        trace(root); //likely null

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageReady, false, 0, true);
        this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, stageUnloaded, false, 0, true); //this is optional

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

private function stageReady(e:Event):void {
    //only listen for frame events once this object has been added to the stage
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

private function stageUnloaded(e:Event):void {
    //stop listening for frame events if this object gets removed from the stage
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}
```